# GridView cell Date Format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, gridview

I want to format Date of the GridView Cell text like

```
ddMMMYYYY
(i.e)
07MAY2010
```

how to achieve this?

```
RowDataBound()
{
....

e.Row.Cells[10].Text = ......?

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do foramte string as shown below do work for you

```
e.Row.Cells[10].Text =String.Format("{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}", dt);
```

with out /

```
e.Row.Cells[10].Text =String.Format("{0:ddMMMyyyy}", dt)
```

More : [String Format for DateTime](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Comment: hi i need without "/" (i.e) 09JUN2010 something like that,it is the requirement